# Integral $\int x^7\cos x^4 dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$\displaystyle \int x^7\cos x^4 dx$

I tried first by letting $x^4 = u$ and then using integration by parts by assigning f(x) to $u^\frac74$ and cos(u) to g'(x) and I end up getting after applying parts twice, the same integral on the RHS as what we are looking for. So I bring it in on the LHS and add it over and get $\displaystyle \cos x^4 \bigg (\frac{\displaystyle 4 \displaystyle u^\frac{11}{4}}{11} \bigg)$

Comment: @King Squirrel This website aims to foster intellectual cooperation. Negativity like that should be avoided, even in jest. Plus, I fixed your formatting -- it was wrong.

Comment: Thank you great sir! The King likes jokes and funnys and his joy should be wanted by all.

Comment: In all seriousness thanks for the edit

Comment: Donald Euclid Knuth to King Squirrel: *There is no Royal Road to LaTeX.* Moderator to All Hands: *The comments were so clearly written in jest that I had to decline the flags. The rude/offensive/spam flags indicate serious offences. A moderator acting upon them increments counters that, when reaching a threshold sum, lead to more serious actions.*

Answer (score 4):

make  a substitution $u = x^4, du = 4x^3 dx.$ the 
$$\int x^7 \cos x^4 \, dx  = \frac14\int u\cos u\, du 
= \frac14 \int u \, d(\sin u) = \frac14 \left( u\sin u -\int \sin u \,du\right)
=\frac14 \left( u\sin u + \cos u\right) + C = \frac14 \left( x^4\sin x^4 + \cos x^4\right) +C  $$

Comment: You should switch back your $u$ to $x^4$ at the end, otherwise +1.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$I=\int x^7 \cos(x^4)\,dx=\frac 14\int (4x^3)\, x^4 \cos(x^4)\,dx$$ So, let $x^4=u$ and then $$I=\frac 14\int u \cos(u) \, du$$ I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: good to see you claude.

Comment: Thanks, abel. It is also my pleasure to meet you quite often here. Cheers :-)